# CUDA memory managment / pointers in classes problems

Tags: c++, c, class, cuda

I am struggling with some memory management problem . I keep receiving "Unspecified launch failure" while copying results to host.

My code is quite simple - it generates two uints in each thread and multiplies them.
I have class for providing a Random Number:

```
class CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider :
{  
public:
    CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider(dim3 numBlocks, dim3 threadsPerBlock);
    CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider(dim3 numBlocks, dim3 threadsPerBlock, unsigned int seed);
    __device__ unsigned int GetRandomNumber();
    ~CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider();
protected:
     curandState * states;
    __device__ bool IsPrime(unsigned int number);
};

CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider::CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider(dim3 numBlocks, dim3 threadsPerBlock)
{
    int numberOfThreads = threadsPerBlock.x * threadsPerBlock.y * numBlocks.x * numBlocks.y;
    std::cout << numberOfThreads << std::endl;
    cudaMalloc ( &this->states, numberOfThreads*sizeof( curandState ) );
    setup_kernel <<< numBlocks, threadsPerBlock >>> ( this->states, time(NULL) );
}

__device__ unsigned int CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider::GetRandomNumber()
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    register float r =  curand_uniform(&this->states[offset]);
    return 0 + ((double)UINT_MAX) * r;
}
```

setup_kernel is stored in header file and looks like this:

```
__global__ void setup_kernel ( curandState * state, unsigned long seed )
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    curand_init ( seed, offset, 0, &state[offset] );
}
```

My main kernel is very simple and looks like this:

```
__global__  void InitKernel(uint3 * ptr, CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider * provider)
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    ptr[offset].x = provider->GetRandomNumber();
    ptr[offset].y = provider->GetRandomNumber();
    ptr[offset].z = ptr[offset].x * ptr[offset].y;
}
```

The execution in main where last cudaMemcpy causes problems is:

```
uint3 * pqnD;

uint3 * pqnH = (uint3*)malloc(sizeof(uint3) * numberOfThreads );
memset(pqnH,0,sizeof(uint3) * numberOfThreads );

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&pqnD, sizeof(uint3) * numberOfThreads ));

CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider * provider = new CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider(numBlocks, threadsPerBlock);

InitKernel<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(pqnD, provider);

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( pqnH, pqnD, sizeof(uint3) * numberOfThreads, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) ); // this line causes error

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree( pqnD ) );
```

If i do everything explicily , like:

```
uint3 * pqnD;

uint3 * pqnH = (uint3*)malloc(sizeof(uint3) * numberOfThreads );

memset(pqnH,0,sizeof(uint3) * numberOfThreads );

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&pqnD, sizeof(uint3) * numberOfThreads ));

curandState * states;

cudaMalloc ( &states, numberOfThreads*sizeof( curandState ) );

setup_kernel <<< numBlocks, threadsPerBlock >>> ( states, time(NULL) );

CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider * provider = new CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider(numBlocks, threadsPerBlock, states);


InitKernel2<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(pqnD, states);

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( pqnH, pqnD, sizeof(uint3) * numberOfThreads, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree( pqnD ) );
```

Where setup_kernel is exactly the same and InitKernel2 looks like:

```
__global__  void InitKernel2(uint3 * ptr, curandState * states)
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    ptr[offset].x = GetRandomNumber(states);
    ptr[offset].y = GetRandomNumber(states);
    ptr[offset].z =     ptr[offset].x *     ptr[offset].y;
}
```

and GetRandomNumber is:

```
__device__ unsigned int GetRandomNumber(curandState * states)
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    register float r =  curand_uniform(&states[offset]);
    return 0 + ((double)UINT_MAX) * r;

}
```

Everything works as a charm. Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong ? I've been struggling with this for hours. I thing it might be something with memory management or pointer passing, but i don't know what could it be.

Please help :)!

Comment: You are supposed to provide an MCVE for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

This is illegal:

```
CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider * provider = new CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider(numBlocks, threadsPerBlock);

InitKernel<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(pqnD, provider);
```

`provider` is a variable that you are allocating on the host.  Passing that pointer to the device and dereferencing it in device code:

```
ptr[offset].x = provider->GetRandomNumber();
```

(ultimately leading to:)

```
register float r =  curand_uniform(&this->states[offset]);
```

is illegal.

Since you seem to want to set up the object (of class `CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider`) on the host and pass it to the device, one possible fix would be to pass the object by value, rather than by pointer.  This would necessitate a few changes, in main:

```
CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider provider(numBlocks, threadsPerBlock);
```

in InitKernel:

```
__global__  void InitKernel(uint3 * ptr, CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider provider) // change
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    ptr[offset].x = provider.GetRandomNumber();  // change
    ptr[offset].y = provider.GetRandomNumber();  // change
    ptr[offset].z = ptr[offset].x * ptr[offset].y;
}
```

in CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider::GetRandomNumber():

```
__device__ unsigned int CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider::GetRandomNumber()
{
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    int offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    register float r =  curand_uniform(&(states[offset])); // change
    return 0 + ((double)UINT_MAX) * r;
}
```

(and I deleted the destructor prototype too, as it was getting in the way.)

Comment: It worked, but passing it via value forces copying this value to every each thread and forces deleting it after execution, am I right ? And as CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider object contains an array of curandState which length is number of threads, things are starting to get little too time-and-memory consuming when it comes ot millions of threads :) I really need to have only one instance of CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider , should i jest cudaMemcpy it to device ? Or use constant memory ?

Comment: `sizeof(CuRandCuRandomNumberProvider)` is 8 bytes on my 64-bit machine, i.e. exactly the size of the `states` *pointer*. That class/object does not contain an array of `curandState`, it contains a *pointer* to that array. And that pointer (like any other kernel argument) will get copied *once* and stored in `__constant__` memory already (on cc2.x and newer devices), so I don't think there's any futher opportunity for efficiency.  I'm not sure what you're concerned about. There's nothing that gets "copied to every thread".  Every thread retrieves the pointer, just as it would have to anyway.

Comment: Anyway, you're welcome to use whatever method you like to fix this.  You asked "Does anyone have a clue what am I doing wrong ?"  What you are doing wrong is allocating a pointer on the host (using `new`) and dereferencing that pointer on the device.   I'm sure there are many ways to solve this problem, I have presented just one.  I don't think there are any significant problems with what I have presented, but if you do, feel free to use another method.